# Remove null column on julia array

Tags: julia

Beggining with Julia, I'm looking to remove the columns with 0 values. I have an array as bellow with a lot of null columns which I would like to remove.

```
115×40 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.0  -0.0  -0.0  -0.0  …  -0.0   0.0  -0.0
  0.0  -0.0  -0.0  -0.0      0.0   0.0   0.0
 -0.0  -0.0  -0.0  -0.0     -0.0   0.0  -0.0
  0.0   0.0  -0.0  -0.0     -0.0   0.0   0.0
  0.0   0.0   0.0  -0.0     -0.0   0.0   0.0
 -0.0   1.0  -0.0   0.0  …  -0.0   0.0   0.0
 -0.0  -0.0   0.0  -0.0     -0.0   0.0   0.0
  0.0  -0.0  -0.0  -0.0      0.0   0.0   0.0
  0.0  -0.0   0.0  -0.0     -0.0   0.0   0.0
  ⋮                      ⋱
  0.0   1.0  -0.0  -0.0      0.0  -0.0  -0.0
 -0.0  -0.0   0.0  -0.0      0.0  -0.0  -0.0
  1.0   0.0  -0.0  -0.0      0.0  -0.0   0.0
 -0.0   0.0  -0.0  -0.0  …   0.0  -0.0  -0.0
  0.0   0.0  -0.0   0.0     -0.0  -0.0  -0.0
 -0.0  -0.0  -0.0   0.0     -0.0  -0.0  -0.0
  0.0  -0.0  -0.0   0.0     -0.0   0.0   0.0
 -0.0  -0.0  -0.0  -0.0     -0.0   1.0   0.0
```

Anyone knows how to do ?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `a` be the array, then

```
a[:, vec(mapslices(col -> any(col .!= 0), a, dims = 1))]
```

works.  `mapslices` reduces `a` to a 1x40 matrix of booleans, indicating the non-zero columns, and we need to convert that to a `Vector` for indexing, hence `vec` (alternatively, one could `dropdims`).

Depending on you application, a [view](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/base/arrays/#Views-(SubArrays-and-other-view-types)-1) instead of a copy might be enough.

Comment: mapslices(col -> all(col .!=0), a, dims = 1) return a complete False array which is not the result expected. 
Setting all(col .==0) indeed return the array where True for null colomns.

What is the operator ≉ used ?

Using mapslices(col -> any(col .!=0), solution_raw, dims = 1) seem to solve this issue

Comment: Of course, I mixed up `any` and `all` when copypasting. `≈` is the operator form of [`isapprox`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/base/math/#Base.isapprox) which I used out of habit, but turns out to be over-cautious: the docs explain that `x ≈ 0` is equivalent to `x == 0` by default. However, if you expect there to be small values, which should be zero mathematically, but aren't numerically, you can use `isapprox` with a non-zero `atol` parameter instead.